# How to use tortoisegit on upgraded hub.jazz.net project?

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops, tortoisegit, ibm-jazz, devops-services

Our company development projet's source control has been hosted on hub.jazz.net for over a year and now the project has just been upgraded to an IBM Bluemix Continuous Delivery toolchain.

Right now the only way I have been able to get oursource and modify it on Windows 7 has been to generate a token on the web site and git clone in a DOS prompt and provide the token as password when prompted.

I have been using TortoiseCVS, TortoiseSVN and TortoiseGit for a dozen years and generating the SSH key with OpenSSL and putting it on the web site works, but TortoiseGit's Pageant does not want to load it.

Does anyone have a procedure that works as of 2017-06 ?

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Robin for getting me to try SSH again, I had given up on it ("immediate gratification always takes too long").

The following recipe now works correctly for me with TortoiseGit version 2.1.0.0. I can clone, commit and push correctly from an updated Bluemix Git repo with TortoiseGit only.

Log in to hub.jazz.net > click My Projects > click project name > click the "use the new toolchain" link > click on the Git link (in the box in the middle)

Copy my project's SSH link that starts with "git@git.ng.bluemix.net"

Click on my name link > click on the pencil image icon on the upper right of the page > click on "SSH Keys" tab

Open Puttygen version 0.67 from my TortoiseGit menu folder > select SSH2-RSA radio button > click Generate button > copy key from field "Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file" (make sure to copy everything by scrolling all the way down, this was likely my mistake earlier) > paste into Bluemix "Key" field of the web page https://git.ng.bluemix.net/profile/keys

In Puttygen, click the "Save private key" button >  Save as PPK extension file in a location you will find easily later.

(optional) In Puttygen, click the "Save public key" button > Save

Open Pageant from TortoiseGit menu folder > this action will bring up an icon in the bottom right of your screen in the Windows taskbar > right-click on icon > select the "Add Key" item in the pop-up menu > add the just-generated private key PPK > right-click on icon > select the "View Keys" item in the pop-up menu > make sure your key was loaded.

Next, open an empty folder in Windows Explorer > right-click in the emptiness > select the "Git Clone..." item in the pop-up menu > this opens the TortoiseGit Clone dialog window > paste the project's SSH link >  enter the desired project branch > Pray > click the "OK" button.

This cloned my Git repo correctly .

I modify a README text file > Commit > Push and that works. We are back in e-business.

I hope this helps out someone else!

Answer (score 0):

I just installed TortoiseGit and Putty and was able to successfully clone a repo from git.ng.bluemix.net via SSH. I followed these directions to ensure I was using Pageant to configure my SSH key: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-ssh-howto.html

Can you share more details on what exactly you're seeing? What happens when you attempt git clone via SSH in a DOS prompt?